# How do you obtain a Drawable object from a resource id in android package?

Tags: android, resources, drawable, android-context

I need to get a Drawable object to display on an image button. Is there a way to use the code below (or something like it) to get an object from the android.R.drawable.* package?

for example if drawableId was android.R.drawable.ic_delete

```
mContext.getResources().getDrawable(drawableId)
```

Answer (score 248, accepted):

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: I also found that using the application context seems to work, thanks.

Comment: As of API 22. `getDrawable(int id)` is deprecated. Use `getDrawable(int id, Resources.Theme theme)` instead. The method `getTheme()` should be helpful.

Comment: I have a small doubt .In this code "The method getDrawable(int) from the type Resources is deprecated".   According to one SO answer 
 

    1. Is it wrong to use Deprecated methods or classes in Java?

From the definition of deprecated: "A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists." What is better alternative for this.

Answer (score 119):

As of **API 21**, you should use the `getDrawable(int, Theme)` method instead of `getDrawable(int)`, as it allows you to fetch a `drawable` object associated with a particular `resource ID` for the given `screen density/theme`. Calling the `deprecated` `getDrawable(int)` method is equivalent to calling `getDrawable(int, null)`.

You should use the following code from the support library instead:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email)
```

Using this method is equivalent to calling:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    return resources.getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
} else {
    return resources.getDrawable(id);
}
```

Comment: `context.getDrawable(id);` seems to be equivalent to `resources.getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());`

Comment: This can be done in one line if you have the support library:
`ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, id, context.getTheme());`

Answer (score 15):

As of API 21, you could also use:

```
   ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.name, null);
```

Instead of `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email)`

Comment: Could you please provide further explanation for the choice

Answer (score 8):

#### From API 21 `getDrawable(int id)` is deprecated

So now you need to use

```
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.img_user, null)
```

#### But Best way to do is :

-
 You should create one common class for getting drawable and colors because if in future have any deprecation then you no need to do changes everywhere in your project.You just change in this method

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat

object ResourceUtils {
    fun getColor(context: Context, color: Int): Int {
        return ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.resources, color, null)
    }

    fun getDrawable(context: Context, drawable: Int): Drawable? {
        return ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.resources, drawable, null)
    }
}
```

use this method like :

```
Drawable img=ResourceUtils.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.img_user)
image.setImageDrawable(img);
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way is

```
 button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
```

**OR** use the below code for Drawable left, top, right, bottom. I'm setting drawable left in this case.

```
int imgResource = R.drawable.left_img;
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imgResource, 0, 0, 0);
```

and

`getResources().getDrawable()` is now deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Following a solution for Kotlin programmers (from API 22)

```
val res = context?.let { ContextCompat.getDrawable(it, R.id.any_resource }
```