# how to get the images from drawable based on xml tag 

Tags: android, xml, drawable

i have an xml which has some custom tags below is the xml:

```
<Point 
   TestFlag="0" id="1" name="Session Introduction"
   practicenaturalfemale="practice_dummy.mp3" practicenaturalmale="practice_dummy.mp3"
   practiceukfemale="practice_dummy.mp3" practiceukmale="practice_dummy.mp3"
   practiceusfemale="practice_dummy.mp3" practiceusmale="practice_dummy.mp3">
   <PracticeText> </PracticeText>
   <PracticeFlag> 0 </PracticeFlag>

    <DownloadFiles />
    <AudioFile gid="1" id="1" name="d001_p001_01.png" type="Img" />
    <AudioFile gid="1" id="2" name="d001_ae_p001_01.png" type="mp3" />
</Point>
```

As you can see there is a image name "d001_p001_01.png" which is image name in `audiofile tag`

i need to pick the image based on this name from the drawable folder how can i acheive 
this.

please help

Comment: I think you are not sure what you want to do. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156698/how-to-get-images-dynamiclly-from-drawable-folder) was your first question and now you had posted another based on that.

Comment: can you get the name d001_p001_01.png as string in code ?

Comment: hello lalit i need to pick the image based on xml tag plz help

Comment: hello babu right now i have added all the images in drawable folder and created array img[] ={R.drawable.doo1}; something like this but i need to get images based on that xml tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("d001_p001_01", "id", getPackageName());
```

Note, name_of_resource should be without extension, d001_p001_01.png shall be d001_p001_01.

use this id to get actual resource:

```
Drawable drawable=getResources().getDrawable(id);
```

Comment: can you please explain what does getResources().getIdentifier(); wil do

Comment: it will return resource id, and you can use this id to get actual resource: by getResources().getDrawable(id);

Comment: fine i agree with you but i need to pick this based on the xml