# open gallery from android studio folder rather than the phone photo gallery

Tags: android, gallery, drawable

I have a activity that select image on the android photo gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.Action_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_OCNTENT_URI);
```

but I want to choose images from my android studio drawable folder instead.
how should I modify the code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't permission for that and that question is already asked

[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156698/how-to-get-images-dynamically-from-drawable-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid there is no `ACTION_PICK` for picking images to project's folder.

But, you may create your own UI to show the images from your project's folder by getting the images using `getIdentifier()` as suggested from the link that Manjeet Deswal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69534358/10467286) provide