# Same image when obtaining drawable object from resource id

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, android-drawable

I have a question. I was searching how I can obtain a drawable object from a resource id. I have already found some ansers on stackoverflow, for example this one: [How do you obtain a Drawable object from a resource id in android package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815689/how-do-you-obtain-a-drawable-object-from-a-resource-id-in-android-package?rq=1)

However for some reason when I use this code I always get the same image, while I have three images in my `res/drawable` folder. I think I am overlooking a small thing but can't find the problem. Could somebody check my code for me?

So when  I change `R.drawable.img_1` to `R.drawable.img_2` the image doesn't change.

Here is the code:

```
public class ShowPaintingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_painting);
        showImage();
    }
    public void showImage() {

        Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.img_1);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageDrawable(d);

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and everything is fine and worked for me. I copy/paste your same code so you have to check your resources name.

Comment: No, the resource names were fine, but i fixed the problem. Look at the update. Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: You should not update your question with the answer instead you have to post your solution as own answer.

Comment: Done! Thank for your advice Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. I had messed up my drawable folder. I think because renaming some files. Fixed the problem by doing the following.

1- go to android studio’s menu bar Build > Rebuild Project

2- go to android studio’s menu bar Build > Clean Project

3- got to android studio’s menu bar File > Invalidate Caches / Restart